# How to center an image without creating a horizontal scroll on smaller screen?

Tags: css, margin, center, display

I'm trying to center my image. I tried 'left: 50%', which kind of worked, but it changed the appearance of the page on a smaller screen by adding a horizontal scroll, which really messed up the look of the whole page (the top and bottom div containers weren't filling the width of the page).

Is there an easy way to center it without causing this horizontal scroll on smaller screens?

```
.top-container {
  background:      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(70deg, #e6739f 30%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 30%), -webkit- linear-gradient(30deg, #cc0e74 60%, #790c5a 60%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(70deg, #e6739f 30%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 30%), -o-linear-gradient(30deg, #cc0e74 60%, #790c5a 60%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(70deg, #e6739f 30%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 30%), -moz-linear-gradient(30deg, #cc0e74 60%, #790c5a 60%);
  background: linear-gradient(70deg, #e6739f 30%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 30%), linear-gradient(30deg, #cc0e74     60%, #790c5a 60%);
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 30px;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
margin: auto;
width: 100vw;

}

.top-container:before {
       content: "";
       background: url("http://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/cubes.png");
       position: absolute;
       top: 0px;
       right: 0px;
       bottom: 0px;
       left: 0px;
       opacity: 0.9;
       width: 100vw;
       height: 100%;
       z-index: -1;
}

nav {
  height: 5vh;
  background: #cc0e74;
  margin-top: -20px;
  width: 100vw;
}

.photo-holder {
  position: relative;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(120deg);
  width: 900px;
  height: 400px;
  max-height: 900px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.photo-holder-inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  background: transparent;
}

.photo-holder-inner-in {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url("./../images/me-skye.JPG");
  background-size: contain;
  filter:hue-rotate(-75deg);
  border:1px solid #a37eba;
}
```

I've probably overlooked something really simple but I'm pretty stuck so any help would b massively appreciated!

Comment: Try set box-sizing: border-box on a root element, like in your html, body or :root selector.

Comment: add HTML codes 

Comment: Sorry - do you mean I should also upload my HTML codes to here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

in the div where u want to center the image or the whole body tag. it will remove horizontal scroll bar.